# Avengers movie - Were the chitauri 'ships' living creatures?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

I repeated the avengers movie yesterday in HD and saw something weird - were the Chitauri 'ships' living creatures? They kinda looked like they had flesh underneath all that metal stuff or did I just see my own stuff?

This is what I'm talking about

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Marvel Movies Wikia](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Leviathan), they are actually called **Leviathans** and they're described as **extraterrestrial animal-slaves**. *(which might be a good name for a punk band)*

> Leviathans are extraterrestrial animal-slaves and warships for the Chitauri. Not much about them is known, only that they are cybernetically-enhanced beasts which aid the Chitauri during their attempted invasion of Earth. They exist in the Marvel Cinematic Universe and first appeared in The Avengers.

They are a completely original creation for the movie, so they won't appear in any other canon:

> The Leviathans are completely original creations by Zak Penn and Joss Whedon and did not appear with the Chitauri in Mark Millar's The Ultimates.

According to the [Marvel Wikia page](http://marvel.wikia.com/Leviathan_(Race)), they were an original creation by [Phil Saunders](http://philsaunders.blogspot.ie/2013/01/more-leviathans.html), here a some of his early sketches:

**And this is completely off-topic, but you should spend a few minutes looking through this guys site, it's pretty impressive.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure would be nice if Wikia cited a source for that info.

Comment: @phantom42 I agree! But it's the best I could find...

Comment: I assumed it was obvious that they were alive: they have teeth; the Chituari fly on the outside, not the inside; and Hulk and Thor drive a metal plate into one's brain to kill it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It wasn't so obvious. The teeth were also metallic which would make someone assume the whole thing was a giant 'robot' kinda thing.